# Getting authorisation for a specific page a user is an administrator for

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am building a CMS where users can add their facebook accounts, and the application will automatically pull in the users posts and display it on the website.

I've got the process of a user authenticating their account and getting their feed data, that's fine.  What I want to do is have some way of getting a user to authenticate a SPECIFIC page that they manage.

I've tried the GET:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=RETURN_URI&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token

but that asks the application to have access to all pages a user manages.

Is there a way I can a) get all the accounts the user has admin rights to and b) get permission to administer a specific page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

no, you can not get specific access for a page - the manage pages permission gives access to all pages the user administers...
With regard to

> a) all the accounts the user has admin rights to

You can use the [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to feel around, check out [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts) in particular - there you can see all the accounts that you have associated with your account.  It uses, as you'll see, the endpoints `/me/accounts`.  But, as you have seen for yourself the permissions dialog that the user is prompted with asks for permission to manage all pages associated with that user.

A suggestion:
When logging into your CMS for the first time, allow your user to select which one (or ones) of the pages he manages should be associated with this CMS.  You don't have to use the access you are granted to the other pages. If you only want to ever integrate **one** page into your CMS just store the `PAGE_ID` (in a database for example) and automatically retrieve it when you need to make calls to and on-behalf of, the page.